# What is the meaning of 'Dodgy Dave'?

Tags: phrase-meaning

After Dennis Skinner's referring to Prime Minister David Cameron as “Dodgy Dave”, I listened this phrase for the first time. But because of being the news so popular, search engines are giving that news as far as I scroll down instead of giving it's meaning.

So, I am asking it here to know the exact meaning of the phrase. I am pretty sure about that it is used for negative sense, but I want to know the exact meaning.

Thanks in advance.

#### EDIT:

Though *Dodgy* could be found from dictionary and *Dave* could be retrieve from intuition, but it is a little bit confusing to the non-English speakers or who use English as second or third language.

Comment: You should try looking up "dodgy" on its own.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I have looked it and I have mentioned that it looks like something negative. But it seemed to me that the whole phrase meant something more specific.

Comment: Since it has someone's name in it, no, it's just a fresh coinage associating an adjective with a name to make an insult.

Comment: @NathanTuggy ow, you meant 'Dave' is the short form of 'David', right?

Comment: Yeah, it is. Looking up "Dave" by itself would also have helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dodgy Dave is an expression made up by Dennis Skinner, it's not a standard expression in the English language. However, English speakers like creating expressions based on alliteration (a string of words that start with the same consonant sound). Some popular examples include:

- *negative Nancy* (used to describe a very pessimistic person)
- *nervous Nellie* (someone who is always nervous)
- *gloomy Gus* (someone who always seems gloomy or down)

In this case, Skinner was simply saying that David Cameron was dodgy, and used the short form of his name to sound condescending.

As a side note: apart from alliteration, expressions with names are often formed based on rhyme (e.g. *plain Jane*).

Answer (score 0):

Dodgy means Dishonest or unreliable (UK English)
Dodgy Dave is adj to the person who sell unreliable things.